# Azure Powershell doesn't expand the result when "select-object" is used

Tags: azure-powershell

I am quite new to Powershell and I use it only for some Azure work I am recently assigned with.

I noticed a behavior that I can't understand. When I run `Get-AzNetworkInterface` cmdlet, the field `IpConfigurations` will displays all details like this

```
IpConfigurations            : [
                            {
                              "Name": "ipconfig1",
                              "Etag": "blabla",
                              "Id": "blabla",
                              "PrivateIpAddress": "10.1.2.3",
                              ....
                            }
                          ]
```

However, if I append `select-object`, the result becomes just the `{ipconfig}`, which is just the name of the field

```
> Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "some nic name" } | Select-Object "IpConfigurations"

IpConfigurations
----------------
{ipconfig1}
```

I have the same result if I view the output with `| Out-Gridview`. The `IpConfigurations` field would only show the name. However, it would also show an `IpConfigurationsText` field that contains all the details. It got truncated so I can't see the full text. By the way, is there a way for the popup GridView window to show the full content? Anyhow, I then tried to select this field in the Shell console but still got nothing.

```
> Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "some nic name" } | Select-Object  IpConfigurationsText

IpConfigurationsText
--------------------
[…
```

What is the logic here for the Azure Powershell cmdlet to expand fields here?
Thanks!
Difan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below cmdlet to expand the `Ipconfigurations` property

```
Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "NICName" } |Select-Object -ExpandProperty IpConfigurations
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

- If you want to expand the `IpConfigurations` Property & project the output in Gridview we would suggest you to use the below PowerShell cmdlet

```html
Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "NICName" } |Select-Object -ExpandProperty IpConfigurations|Out-GridView -PassThru
```

**Here is the sample output for reference** :

[image]

Comment: Great response! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, a quick follow-up question... Can I not select multiple objects and expand them like this? `Get-AzNetworkInterface | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IpConfigurations,VirtualMachine`? I got this error `Select-Object: Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specified method is not supported.`. Thanks!